# Unable to set an action extension icon, grey icon instead

Tags: ios, ios-extensions

I've tried to set my action extension icon by following [tutorials available online](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-how-to-build-a-simple-action-extension--cms-22794). The steps I've followed:

1. Migrate the application asset catalog to the extension
2. Putting all my grey icons in the asset
3. Checking that `Assets.xcassets`is in the copy bundle resources list of the extension
4. Run the app and check the extension

But it only renders a grey block:
[image: grey block and other icons]

What could be wrong?

Comment: Have you checked that the img alpha is ok? Just open it with preview and check that you see a light gray background. If you have any other color, it will render grey

Comment: You can just use GIMP, or any other free editor to change the background color of an image :)

Comment: They use the same restrictions as tab or bar button icons
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/BarIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH21-SW1

Comment: Thanks! I was only reading this page https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppExtensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH67-SW3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Action Extension Icon, **any color data in the image itself is ignored**. as stated in [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIActivity/activityImage)

> The alpha channel of the image is used as a mask to generate the final
>   image that is presented to the user. Any color data in the image
>   itself is ignored.

***To fix this issue, follow these 4 step***

1. First remove alpha channel from your icon using
           [tinypng.com](https://tinypng.com)   or   [alphaChannelRemover app](http://alphachannelremover.blogspot.in)
2. added a new Asset Catalog set to my extension by right click  -> New
   File -> under IOS  choose “Resource” -> Asset Catalog
3. In that Asset Catalog, I added an new AppIcon, using the + menu at
   the bottom. Note the name is: AppIcon, then added your removed alpha
   icons to the new AppIcon.
4. Then under Targets, I selected my extension, then under Build
   Settings under Asset Catalog Compiler - Options, I added AppIcon to
   the Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name field.

[image]

Comment: You can use Apple's Preview to export PNGs without alpha channel